# Measuring how good is one feature in predicting another

Tags: accuracy, measurement

I'm looking for a way to measure, how well one feature lets us predict the value of another.
Let's say we have a car with multiple sensors. Their role is to check whether the upcomming turn is left or right. We're collecting data from all sensors and also from steering wheel. Then we want to choose sensor, based on which we're gonna build autonomic steering system.

I've got two example datasets: 
[image: sensor 1][image: sensor 2]

As you can see, with the first chart, we can easily say, that if prediction value is less than 0, then steering value should be greater than 0, which isn't so obvious on chart 2.
But how to measure it?

Comment: Why do you want to select ONLY one sensor?

Comment: It's theoretical situation. In fact it's not important how many sensors I'll use, but which of them deliver meaningul information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is possible that a combination of some variables delivers meaningful information, but a single one is worthless by itself. Consider for example, `Z = X xor Y` where `X` and `Y` are two random binary variables. Here, with `X` OR `Y` we cannot say anything about `Z`, but with `X` AND `Y` we can completely determine the value of `Z`. Anyway, to determine the variables that are influential in predicting a target variable, if the number of your sensors are small, you can do an exhaustive search: produce all subsets of the variables, and for each subset, try cross-validation on that subset to determine the success of that subset in predicting your target. If the number of sensors is large, you should adopt a greedy approach. Take a look at stepwise regression method as a potential solution to your problem.